# When to use $this->property instead of $property in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Super easy question.  Look at the 2 sample class methods.

In the first One I pass in a variable/property call `$params` I then do `$this->params`

My question is, is it really needed, I generally do it this way but I have noticed that it will work in the second example with just calling `$params`  without setting `$this` to it.

So my theory is this... You have to set it like `$this->params` if you need to access that property in a different method in that class and you can use just `$params` if you are only using that property in that same method it is in already.

Could somebody shed some light on this and explain if my theory is correct or if I am way off I would like to know the reasoning for this so I will know when do do each method or to do one or the other all the time, thanks you

```
class TestClass{

    public function TestFunc($params){
       $this->params = $params;

       echo 'testing this something'. $this->params;
    }
}
```

without defining variables

```
class TestClass2{

    public function TestFunc2($params){
       echo 'testing this something'. $params;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you do in your first function is you read the parameters that get passed to the function, and save them in to a class variable. It makes no sense if used like in the example but if you want to store the variable then this is kind of how a "set function" works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$this` when accessing class variables.

When accessing a variable which is actually a parameter in a function, there's no need to utilize the `$this` keyword.. Actually, to access the function parameter named $params, you should not use the $this keyword...

In your example:

```
class TestClass{

    public function TestFunc($params){
       $this->params = $params;

       echo 'testing this something'. $this->params;
    }
}
```

`$params` from `TestFunc($params){` is a parameter/argument of the function `TestFunc` and so you don't need to use `$this`. In fact, to access the parameter's value, you must not use `$this` -- Now when you used `$this->params` from `$this->params = $params = $params;`, you are actually setting a value equivalent to that of the *parameter* `$params` to a NEW class-level variable named *also* `$params` (since you didn't declare it anywhere in your sample code)

[edit] based on comment:

Look at this example:

```
class TestClass{

    public function TestFunc($params){
       $this->params = $params;
       # ^ you are setting a new class-level variable $params
       # with the value passed to the function TestFunc 
       # also named $params

       echo 'testing this something'. $this->params;
    }

    public function EchoParameterFromFunction_TestFunc() {
        echo "\n\$this->params: " . $this->params . "\n";
        # now you are echo-ing the class-level variable named $params
        # from which its value was taken from the parameter passed
        # to function TestFunc
    }

}

$tc = new TestClass();
$tc->EchoParameterFromFunction_TestFunc(); # error: undefined property TestClass::$params
$tc->TestFunc('TestFuncParam');
$tc->EchoParameterFromFunction_TestFunc(); # should echo: $this->params: TestFuncParam
```

The error when you called `EchoParameterFromFunction_TestFunc` without first calling `TestFunc` is a result of not declaring/setting the class-level variable/property named `$params` --you set this up inside `TestFunc`, which means it doesn't get set unless you call `TestFunc`. To set it right so that anyone can immediately access it is to:

```
class TestClass{
    # declare (and set if you like)
    public /*or private or protected*/ $params; // = ''; or create a construct...

    public function __construct(){
        # set (and first declare if you like)
        $this->params = 'default value';
    }
...
...
...
```

[edit : additional]

As **@liquorvicar** mentioned, which I also totally agree with is that you should always declare all your class-level properties/variables, regardless of whether or not you will use them. Reason being and as an example is that you don't want to access a variable that hasn't been set. See my example above which threw the error `undefined property TestClass::$params`..

Thanks to @liquorvicar for reminding me..

Comment: So if a function parameter is needed in another function as well, then I would have to use $this->$param right?

Comment: If you use $this->var then you can access this variable in all methods within the same class (like "global" in this class).

Comment: Probably worth adding that you should declare all class properties (and you don't really explain that term to the OP).

Comment: @jasondavis, please take a look at the updated post. As liquorvicar stated, you should declare all class-level properties. :)

Comment: Thanks, I had a pretty good idea, now I know for sure.  I used to actually declare all my properties with `$this->` now it makes more sense to only do it with class variables

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. Your explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help clear things up:

```
class Person {

   private $name;
   private $age;

   public function __construct($name, $age){
     // save func params to instance vars
     $this->name = $name;
     $this->age = $age;
   }

   public function say_hello(){ // look, no func params!
     echo "My name is {$this->name} and I am {$this->age} years old!";
   }

   public function celebrate_birthday(){ // no params again
     echo "Party time!";
     $this->age += 1; // update instance var
     $this->drink_beer();  // call instance method
   }

   public function drink_beer(){
     echo "Beer is good!";
   }
}

$p = new Person("Sample", "20");
$p->say_hello();          // My name is Sample and I am 20 years old!
$p->celebrate_birthday(); // Party time! Beer is good!
$p->say_hello();          // My name is Sample and I am 21 years old!
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use specific variable when they're in the context ("scope") of your object.

In OOP programming, `$this` will almost always be used to access a class variable or other class method.

```php
class MyClass{
     private $myNum;

     public function myFunc(){
          echo 'My number is '.$this->myNum; // Outputting the class variable "myNum"
     }

     public function go($myNumber){
          $this->myNum  = $myNumber; // Will set the class variable "$myNum" to the value of "$myNumbe" - a parameter fo the "go" function.
          $this->myFunc(); // Will call the function "myFunc()" on the current object
     }
}
```

Shai.

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your question yourself:

> You have to set it like $this->params if you need to access that
>   property in a different method in that class and you can use just
>   $params if you are only using that property in that same method it is
>   in already

Answer (score 0):

Your own theory

> You have to set it like `$this->params` if you need to access that property in a different method in that class and you can use just `$params` if you are only using that property in that same method it is in already.

is a good guideline, but it falls somewhat short. Consider

```
public function applyDiscount($discount)
{
    if ($this->isValidDiscountRangeForProduct($discount)) {
        $this->price -= $this->price * $discount;
    }
}
```

You would not assign `$discount` to an object property just because you needed to validate it before applying it to the `$this->price` (use in other method). A better guideline would be

***If the argument is only used to calculate internal state of the object, you don't make it a property.***

Also, keep in mind that a method like your

```
public function TestFunc2($params)
{
   echo 'testing this something' . $params;
}
```

is likely misplaced on that object because it has no *cohesion*. You only want methods on your object that operate on the data of this object in some way. Attaching methods that do not operate on the object members is like tucking an ice crusher onto your car:

```
class Car 
{
    public function crushIce($ice)
    {
        // WTF!?
    }
}
```

Further resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29