# Can't fix some errors with OOP: relating to constructor calling function

Tags: php, oop

I am really **new** to OOP, and I am getting some errors with my first implementation of the __constructor method. The two errors are:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _test in...

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in ...
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php


class Info
{
    private static $_test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setIt(); //call setIt so $_test can be set to true or false for use by other functions in the class.
    }
    public function setIt()
    {
        if ("test" == "something") //simplified logic for demo purposes
            $this->$_test = TRUE;
        else
            $this->$_test = FALSE;
    }

    public function getIt()
    {
        if ($this->$_test) { //if test is true or false do stuff/other stuff
            //do stuff
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    }
}
$myObj = new Info(); //initialise the object

?>
<?php echo $myObj->getIt(); ?> //surrounded by html in my original code. Here I am getting some 'stuff' or 'other stuff' depending on what setIt() returned to $_test.
```

Sorry if that is a bit convoluted.

Comment: `$this->_test` not `$this->$_test`; the latter would be a variable variable reference... i.e. if local var `$_test` has value "foo", then it's trying to set `$this->foo`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: `$_test` is marked `static` so you can't access it with `$this` use `SELF::$_test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accessing your property with a $ at the beginning of it. When accessing object properties in an object scope, you dont need to use `$`. However, you've declared `$_test` as static, so you would set / get them using `self::$_test`

```
class Info
{
    private static $_test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setIt(); 
    }

    public function setIt()
    {
        if ("test" == "something"){
            self::$test = TRUE;
        } else {
            self::$test = FALSE;
    }

    public function getIt()
    {
        if (self::$_test) { 
            //do stuff
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    }
}
$myObj = new Info(); //initialise the object

echo $myObj->getIt();
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
$this->$_test = TRUE;
```

with

```
$this->_test = TRUE;
```

every where in you code.

While using `$this` then `$` is not used with property name

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428388/when-to-use-this-property-instead-of-property-in-php) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `$_test` as `static`, so you should access it as:

```
self::$_test
```

or

```
static::$_test
```

Still, getters and setters should be meaningful, and be named after the field they are wrapping [i.e. `getTest()`, `setTest($value)`], even if you are just providing an example case.

If you are new to OOP, you'll be going to some troubles with understanding the difference between instance and `static` properties and methods.

Let's pretend to have a `Circle` class, which holds center and radius:

```
class Circle
{

  public static PI = 3.141592653589793;

  private $x;
  private $y;
  private $radius;

  public function getX(){ return $this -> x;}
  public function setX($x){ $this -> x = $x;}

  public function getY(){ return $this -> y;}  
  public function setY($y){ $this -> y = $y;}

  public function getRadius(){ return $this -> radius;}  
  public function setRadius($radius){ $this -> radius = $radius;}  

  public function __construct($x, $y, $radius)
  {

    $this -> setX($x);
    $this -> setY($y);
    $this -> setRadius($radius);

  }

  public function getArea()
  {

    return $this -> radius * $this -> radius * self::PI;

  }

  public function getLength()
  {

    return 2 * self::PI * $this -> radius;

  }

}
```

`x`, `y` and `radius` are different for each circle [instance of the class] you build: they are *instance variables*:

```
$firstCircle = new Circle(0,0,10);
$secondCircle = new Circle(5,5,2);
...
```

On the other hand, `PI` is static because it belongs to the class itself: for every circle it holds that the length/diameter ratio is 3.1415...

You'll find out that static properties and methods have wider use in OOP, but that's enough in order to have a first glance into it.